# What aspects of normal human behavior have people mistaken as the work of the flesh?

Tags: sin, morality, good-and-evil, galatians

In Galatians 5, Paul helps us understand the work of the flesh, such as in verse 17:
"For the desires of the flesh are against the Spirit, and the desires of the Spirit are against the flesh, for these are opposed to each other, to keep you from doing the things you want to do" (ESV).

Also in vv. 19-21:
"Now the works of the flesh are evident: sexual immorality, impurity, sensuality, idolatry, sorcery, enmity, strife, jealousy, fits of anger, rivalries, dissensions, divisions, envy, drunkenness, orgies, and things like these. I warn you, as I warned you before, that those who do such things will not inherit the kingdom of God" (ESV).

The main identifier of the flesh seems to be in v. 17, as being against the Spirit.

In what ways do we mistake normal weaknesses in our bodies and faculties as the flesh when they are not? What examples would help us know the difference, and perhaps not feel guilty and attempt wrong solutions for recovery?

Answer (score 5):

"Normal human behavior" is described in the Bible as "sinful behavior". Even when it does not appear that any action or speech is sinful, or 'weak', the Bible states that even our righteous acts are as filthy rags in God's sight (Isaiah 64:6).  Paul quotes from that section in Isaiah, applying it to his day. Romans 3:9 starts:

> "We have already made the charge that Jews and Gentiles alike are all
> under sin. As it is written, 'There is no-one righteous, not even
> one...'(and more from Isaiah chapter 64.) N.I.V.

The best way to get a satisfactory answer to the question is to look at the problem from God's point of view, as he is the holy, righteous judge. But if sinful people judge themselves according to their idea of what sin is (or isn't), they might easily salve their consciences and excuse themselves: especially if the object of the exercise is to *"not feel guilty"!*

A problem, though, is how judgmental and legalistic many people are on the topic of identifying "works of the flesh". They take the clear, straight-forward warning of Paul (which you quoted) and declare all sorts of things as being 'unclean' or 'fleshly'. Prohibitions start to abound. Punishments are threatened, and poor souls end up so fixated on what they should, or should not do, they have a massive guilt complex - all because of what other people say or expect.

Paul is quite clear, and if taken in context, from verse 1, it's obvious he is contrasting how those without the indwelling Holy Spirit struggle and how they live, whereas Christians who have the Holy Spirit live in his freedom, and are alert not to let themselves be caught in a yoke of sinful slavery again. Now, if a person has never yet come to new, spiritual birth by the Holy Spirit, they have never been set free from the burden of their sins. Their consciences will either keep condemning them, or become hardened, seared as with a branding iron. There is no "solution for recovery". The Bible says the sinful human nature has to be "crucified" - put to death. It's not supposed to "recover". It's supposed to be destroyed utterly! And only a miracle of grace will do that.

> "Those who belong to Christ Jesus have crucified the sinful nature
> with its passions and desires. Since we live by the Spirit, let us
> keep in step with the Spirit." Galatians 5:24-25, N.I.V.

Us sinners have to admit to God that his judgment of us is entirely true and that we deserve his wrath. We have to start seeing the enormity of our sin, from his point of view, which should get us on our knees in confession and repentance. When we waken up to the fact that we are lost in our sin, we cry out to God for mercy and forgiveness. We believe that Jesus died to deal with our sin, and that only faith in what he did to deliver us into new, spiritual life will destroy our sinful nature. Then we will "belong to Christ". Then liberation will come. The sinful nature will no long control us. We will have a new master, being willing slaves of Christ. And the Holy Spirit will continue his work in us for the rest of our lives. As we grow in grace, taught of the Spirit, the flesh will have less and less of an appeal to us. Spiritual things will become our priority.

Comment: Your answer is borne out by the scripture, "Whatever is not of faith is sin."

Comment: @Steve What an excellent scripture to quote! Romans 14:23

Comment: I'm thinking that the book, _The Christian's Secret of a Happy Life,_ by Hannah Whitall Smith, answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

### Trivializing Sin

The reason why people trivialize the definition or standard of sin is, ironically, to justify sinning. The wrong and twisted standard of transgression to God is deliberately created to make repentance impossible, thereby, inventing a nominal salvation from nominal sin. When sin and righteousness cease to be real, it becomes nominal. It can be justified by misinterpretation of certain out of context snippets from the Bible, such as 1 John 1:8 to argue that one cannot be sinless, ignoring the fact that the epistle is the most thorough writing defining sin, and preventing (real) sin and leading a complete sanctified life to the church influenced by fleshly gnostic philosophy or mindset. The common examples of such low view of sin and righteousness can be seen all around the Western Christians in any online discussion if you rebuke someone's eisegesis, e.g.

> Are you saying you are sinlessly perfect. Did you not know the thought of foolishness is sin? It is quite impossible to go 1 day without sin. Any thought that isn't holy and perfect is sin.

To them, no act of man can be good, even breathing is sinful, [man is born utterly and depravedly sinful](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506141138/http://ecclesia.org/truth/original_sin.html).

### Solution

The right solution would be to get rid of the fleshly theology, and re-read the Bible, as it is the source that describes and define sin. The most important book on this subject is John's epistles, as he defines sin to the gnostics who thought man cannot be cleansed from unrighteousness, because they do not desire to be freed from the bondage of sin. Recognise the difference between true and false righteousness as well as sin, and remember that there is degree of sin, there are sins that do not lead to death 1Jn 5:16. When the hypocrite, false righteousness of the religious Priests or Scholars cannot save them, then the false (pseudo) sins of a good man cannot condemn or disqualify him (Matt 5:20). See Acts 10:35, [Romans 2:6-16](http://biblehub.net/search.php?q=according%20to%20works). Realise that sin is a moral and spiritual moral failure, not a virus with which we are born with.

> [(NCB)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2064:4-6&version=NCB) Isaiah 64:5
> You welcome those who lead an upright life
> and rejoice to imitate your ways.
> When we sin, you become angry,
> but when we follow your ways,
> we know that we will be saved.

Michael Brown has written in detail against [Hyper-Grace](https://www.google.com/search?q=michael+brown+hyper+grace&hl=en&gl=in&tbm=bks&uact=5), using examples of popular Western Christians like [Paul Ellis](https://escapetoreality.org/2011/11/28/3-reasons-why-i-dont-preach-on-repentance/) who believe that doctrines based on behavioural change, or works based repentance nullifies grace.

Some weak-minded people live in fear and try to scare others that Yoga exercise is sin, something which may help their sick bodies. Thus, exercise, healthy diet, meditation may be some of the things where people falsely characterise as sin. Some believe modern music instruments in Church is sin; some would find observing some cultural customs and food would be sin, or not eating or observing the customs is sin.

Comment: Paul took the time to write a graphic list of what sins look like in the Galatians passage. What activities do people think are sinful and yet in themselves are not really sinful?

Comment: U want references from preachers?

Comment: Sure! I'll take what I can get. Some might say playing cards or dancing, for instance. But that's not exactly what I meant. I'm thinking more about attitudes, like defeat at a game.

Comment: I couldn't find such examples of trivialisation of sin in Dr browns books Go sin no more and hyper grace. I conclude that the trivialisation (total depravity) leads to complete denial of sin among those believers as they preach against repentance. I will check about other examples however, describing sin, fear as sin must mean a different connotation than actual sin as it's meant for motivation and rhetorical purpose. Shouldn't take those in the same way as sin.

Comment: Paul talks about eating meat without asking if they have been offered to idols. Some, weak in the faith, are stumbled by eating such meat. We know it is not sin, but it will appear as sin to those of a wounded conscience.

Comment: "Some believe modern music instruments in Church is sin", that's a gross oversimplification. To be sure, some people probably o oversimplify such that your statement is true. However, implying that they just *aren't*, full stop, is also not entirely true. For that matter, the same is true with Yoga! *Exercises* aren't sinful in and of themselves, but Yoga mixes exercise with idolatrous philosophy. Similarly with "meditation".

Comment: On a more general note, this feels... twisted. Humans *can't* be sinless, and yes, we *are* born sinful (that is, with a will that is, by itself, hopelessly inclined to sin). I don't know how you get from there to "repentance is impossible", however, unless you are misusing "repent". Nor does the doctrine of total depravity trivialize sin; on the contrary, it goes to *emphasize* how utterly lost we are on our own. To deny that helplessness is to open the door to believing that we can save ourselves, which is a) idolatry, b) the fatal flaw in every man-made religion.

Comment: To over-simplify: the Hebrew scriptures taught that sin is in what we *do*; Jesus taught that sin is also in what we *think*, and the Roman Church taught that sin is also in what we *are*. Actions come from thoughts, which come from innateness. Jews build on their deeds, Christians build on their attitudes, and Catholics build on their guilt.